# How to get a list of Domain Admin users from a windows 2003 DC

Tags: active-directory, scripting, windows-command-prompt, vbscript

I'm trying to get a list of domain admin users from my Windows Server 2003 domain controller. I am unable to obtain it with powershell because the ActiveDirectory module is not installed.

I need to obtain it from CMD.

I have tried `net group /domain "Domain Admins"` and while this returns all the Domain Admin users I need the following format which I don't know how to obtain. Any ideas?

The list should contain:

```
User name (Baker, John for example)
sAMAccountName (`I can obtain this with net /group`)
Account creation date
Last logon date
If the account is enabled or not
```

EDIT: I have tried `dsquery group -name "Domain Admins" | dsget group -members -expand` but I don't get the expected output either.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's so obsolete it makes me cry.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dsget group <group DN> -members -expand > Group_Members.txt
```

The created document now contains the DN of each member of the group. You can then use this to get more details for each user

```
dsget user <user DN>
```

Comment: I have tried `dsget group "Domain Admins" -members -expand` but got the following error: `dsget failed:Value for 'Target object for this command' has incorrect format.`. Am I not using it right?

Comment: You need to use the DistinguishedName attribute.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, however I only got the domain admin user names and the OU they belong to, any idea how I can get the rest of the details i need? Account creation, when was the account created, and whether it is enabled or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ADGroupMember "Domain Admins" | select name, objectclass, samaccountname >>C:\Users\[username]\Desktop\domainadmin.txt
```

Run in ad powershell

2003 not sure whether AD power shell can be imported or not .

Answer (score -2):

```
$ADGroup = Read-Host "Please enter the AD Group Name to Query"
$ExportPath = Read-Host "Please Enter Fully Qualified Path to Export Query Resluts"
$LogonTime = Get-ADGroup "$ADGroup" | Get-ADGroupMember | Get-ADUser -Properties * | select bla, bla, bla.....
$LogonTime | Export-Csv "$ExportPath\$ADGroup-LogOnInfo.csv"
```